# PL/SQL - printing a value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a field `Base` that has the values for example `0000000000`. I need to print it in txt file through stored procedure. Its data type is CHAR(10). But while printing it is just printing a single value like 0.

Please give me the suggestions to correct this.

Comment: CHAR values are printed as they are. It probably gets converted to a NUMERIC value somewhere along the way.

Comment: How can I make it to display as it is?

Comment: Make sure it is always treated as a CHAR (and never as a NUMERIC).

Answer (score 1):

**Option1:**

You should try using LPAD function.

```
Select LPAD(Columnname, 10, '0') from yourtable;
```

**Option2:**

try forcing `TO_CHAR` while printing

Answer (score 0):

maybe your procedure implicitly convert your column to number.
try to change the call of your column to by explicit char by call to_char(column_name) in your procedure.